# ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'UXCamBridge.startWithConfiguration') for android devices issue

Tags: react-native, uxcam

I have getting

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'UXCamBridge.startWithConfiguration') in android devices.

Setup for UXCam for android devices

Issue in this line:

```
RNUxcam.startWithConfiguration(configuration);
```

[image]